# Identify if files are being transferred from my computer over the internet

Tags: firewalls

This may seem like a silly question to most, but...

I recently has some spyware infected on my machine, which I have since gotten rid of.
Using a couple of scanners (that come recommended on various sites such as c|net etc) do not show any more signs of viruses etc. Yay!

Being as paranoid as I am, I'm wanting to check (or get confirmation) that nothing is being taken from my Laptop over my internet connection.

I regularly monitor DL and UL speeds which remain low, but I'm not sure whether or not that's confirmation.

Is there anything I can do or install that will let me see what's being transferred (if any) over my internet connection?

I hope I've made sense. It's my first time here so sorry for any naivety.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Broadly speaking, you could install a local [transparent proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy) to gain more insight into network activity. This can be done with free software, like [Squid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29), and there are commercial products that do similar things.

You could also use a DNS provider that does logging and filtering, like [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/). This will let you see what connections your computer is making.

Both the proxy and DNS methods above will not catch all malicious network activity, and are quite complex and time consuming to setup.

If your goal is to guarantee that your computer is infection free, then you should backup your files and **rebuild from know good media**. That means to format the hard drive(s), and reinstall the operating system from a recovery CD (or similar).

It will be faster, safer, and more reliable to rebuild than to try and "keep watch" on a maybe-infected machine.

Answer (score 3):

No chance. If the spyware encrypts the traffic, you can not see what has been transmitted. The only thing you can do is monitoring which program opens which file. That can be done by the operating system. It has been discussed here already: [Monitoring file access on Windows](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6702/monitoring-file-access-on-windows)